# How to prove that $\mathbb Z/p$ is not a direct summand of any direct sum of copies of $\mathbb Z/n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

How can I prove that $\mathbb Z/p$  ($p$ is a prime) cannot be a direct summand of any arbitrary direct sum of copies of $\mathbb Z/n$, where $p^2$ divides $n$?

Comment: Because, if $p^2|n$, then $p|(n/p)$, and ${\mathbb Z}_p \oplus {\mathbb Z}_{n/p}$ is not cyclic, because all of its elements have orders that divide $n/p$.

Comment: It is not a direct summand of Zn. Does this imply that it is not direct summand of any arbitrary direct sum of Zn?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by an arbitrary direct sum of ${\mathbb Z}_n$. Obviously it is a direct summand of ${\mathbb Z}_n \oplus {\mathbb Z}_p$.

Comment: A direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}/n$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $\mathbb{Z}/p$ is a direct summand of $\bigoplus_{i \in I} \mathbb{Z}/n$. We may assume $n=p^2$ after dividing by $p^2$. The image is generated by some element of order $p$, say $b=(b_i \bmod p^2)_{i \in I}$. Since $p b_i \equiv 0 \bmod p^2$, we may write $b_i = p a_i$. If $b_i=0$, we choose $a_i=0$. It follows that $a:=(a_i)_{i \in I}$ is an element of the direct sum such that $b=pa$. But then every homomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}/p$ kills $b$, a contradiction.

Comment: It might help to put this into words. Every element of order $p$ in $\oplus_{i \in I}{\mathbb Z}/n$ is a $p$th power of some other element. But ${\mathbb Z}/p \oplus X$ contains an element of order $p$ that is not a $p$th power.